# jQuery .show not working in .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, show

Here is my jquery code.I'm trying to show.Here is my code

```
 $('#divTalentAgent a').each(function () {
        $(this).show();
    });
```

The above code doesn't work.But if i modify it as below

```
 $('#divTalentAgent a').each(function () {
        alert('hi');
        $(this).show();
    });
```

It works..

Comment: can you post a fiddle reproducting this effect ?

Comment: Where are you running the code? Is it inside a `$(document).ready` call?

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that the `#divTalentAgent a` hasn't been rendered yet and hence with the alert (which pauses execution until clicked) you are getting the rendered divs being shown properly.  Have you tried putting your code in the jQuery ready function?
http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @RichardDalton no its not

Comment: If all you want to do is call `.show();`, then you don't need to the `each` loop. See `Itiel` answer below

Comment: @RobSchmuecker not a possiblity since doing alert($(this).attr('id')) gives me the correct ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 $('#divTalentAgent a').each(function () {
   setTimeout(function(){$(this).show();},0);       
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct code is:

```
$('#divTalentAgent a').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#divTalentAgent a').show();
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Its working

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('li').each(function () {
        alert('hi');
        $(this).show();
    });
      });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/RX4BT/18/)